# PERMISSION_DENIED error when calling runJob() with Cloud Scheduler API client for Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a scheduled Firebase Cloud Function to run daily:

```
const doSomething = functions.region("europe-west1").pubsub
  .schedule("0 0 * * *").onRun(
....
)
```

This is working fine and the job appears in the Cloud Schedule console. But I also want to run the same function at an arbitrary time from another app, using the [runJob()](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-scheduler/blob/d8bc4b40a464834b72868eaf244b5d8dd58878e7/src/v1/cloud_scheduler_client.ts#L911) method at Cloud Scheduler API client for Node.js (@google-cloud/scheduler). This is the code that should force the job to run:

```
const { CloudSchedulerClient } = require('@google-cloud/scheduler');
const client = new CloudSchedulerClient();
const jobId = "firebase-schedule-doSomething-europe-west1";
const job = client.jobPath(projectId, "europe-west1", jobId);
const request = { name: job }
await client.runJob(request);
```

When running the previous code, I get the following error:

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudscheduler.jobs.run" for the resource "projects/myfirstproject/locations/europe-west1/jobs/firebase-schedule-doSomething-europe-west1" (or the resource may not exist).
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/Users/gparis/myservice/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/gparis/myservice/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/gparis/myservice/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/gparis/myservice/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
at /Users/gparis/myservice/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
....
```

At "Service Account logs" in the Cloud Console, I see this error:

```
2021-09-22T15:09:23.523080936Z Cloud Scheduler API RunJob europe-west1:firebase-schedule-doSomething-europe-west1 firebase-adminsdk-xxxxx@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I think my service account has Google-provided role grants for Cloud Scheduler. Is there something I am missing to be able to run this scheduled cloud function from the API client?

Comment: Can you try give the service account the IAM permission the error throws?

Comment: I took a second look at it, and indeed I have solved the problem by adding the `Cloud Scheduler Job Runner` role  to the service account. This role includes the `cloudscheduler.jobs.run` permission.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!